# How can I do a Monte Carlo analysis on an equation?

Tags: python, montecarlo

Given a function that depends on multiple variables, each with a certain probability distribution, how can I do a Monte Carlo analysis to obtain a probability distribution of the function. I'd ideally like the solution to be high performing as the number of parameters or number of iterations increase.

As an example, I've provided an equation for `total_time` that depends on a number of other parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 1000

gym = [30, 30, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 40, 45, 45]

left = 5
right = 10
mode = 9
shower = np.random.triangular(left, mode, right, size)

argument = np.random.choice([0, 45], size, p=[0.9, 0.1])

mu = 15
sigma = 5 / 3
dinner = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size)

mu = 45
sigma = 15/3
work = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size)

brush_my_teeth = 2

variables = gym, shower, dinner, argument, work, brush_my_teeth
for variable in variables:
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(variable)
plt.show()


def total_time(variables):
    return np.sum(variables)
```

**gym**
[image: gym]

**shower**
[image: shower]

**dinner**
[image: dinner]

**argument**
[image: argument]

**work**
[image: work]

**brush_my_teeth**
[image: brush_my_teeth]

Comment: Have you tried the [pymc](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/tutorial.html) package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The existing answer has the right idea, but I doubt you want to sum all of the values in `size` as nicogen has done.

I assume you were picking a relatively large `size` to demonstrate the shape in the histograms and instead you want to sum up one value from each category. e.g., we want to compute the sum of one instance of each activity, not 1000 instances.

The first code block assumes that you know your function is a sum and can therefore use fast numpy summing to compute the sum.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mc_trials = 10000

gym = np.random.choice([30, 30, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
                    35, 35, 40, 40, 40, 45, 45], mc_trials)
brush_my_teeth = np.random.choice([2], mc_trials)
argument = np.random.choice([0, 45], size=mc_trials, p=[0.9, 0.1])
dinner = np.random.normal(15, 5/3, size=mc_trials)
work = np.random.normal(45, 15/3, size=mc_trials)
shower = np.random.triangular(left=5, mode=9, right=10, size=mc_trials)

col_per_trial = np.vstack([gym, brush_my_teeth, argument,
           dinner, work, shower])

mc_function_trials = np.sum(col_per_trial,axis=0)

plt.figure()
plt.hist(mc_function_trials,30)
plt.xlim([0,200])
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

If you don't know your function, or can't easily recast is as a numpy element-wise matrix operation, you can still loop through like so:

```
def total_time(variables):
        return np.sum(variables)

mc_function_trials = [total_time(col) for col in col_per_trial.T]
```

You ask about obtaining the "probability distribution".  Getting the histogram as we have done above doesn't quite do that for you.  It gives you a visual representation, but not the distribution function.  To get the function, we need to employ kernel density estimation.  scikit-learn has a canned [function and example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_kde_1d.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-kde-1d-py) that does this.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
mc_function_trials = np.array(mc_function_trials)
kde = (KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=2)
       .fit(mc_function_trials[:, np.newaxis]))

density_function = lambda x: np.exp(kde.score_samples(x))

time_values = np.arange(200)[:, np.newaxis]
plt.plot(time_values, density_function(time_values))
```

[image]

Now you can compute the probability of the sum being less than 100, for instance:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
probability, accuracy = integrate.quad(density_function, 0, 100)
print(probability)
# prints 0.15809
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with a simple `for` loop? First, define your constants and function. Then, run a loop n times (10'000 in the example), drawing new random values for the variables and calculating the function result each time. Finally, append all results to `results_dist`, then plot it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gym = [30, 30, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 40, 45, 45]
brush_my_teeth = 2
size = 1000

def total_time(variables):
    return np.sum(variables)

results_dist = []
for i in range(10000):
    shower = np.random.triangular(left=5, mode=9, right=10, size)
    argument = np.random.choice([0, 45], size, p=[0.9, 0.1])
    dinner = np.random.normal(mu=15, sigma=5/3, size)
    work = np.random.normal(mu=45, sigma=15/3, size)

    variables = gym, shower, dinner, argument, work, brush_my_teeth

    results_dist.append(total_time(variables))

plt.figure()
plt.hist(results_dist)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems almost right, however, I think the poster had intended the `gym` list to represent a probability distribution, and you don't seem to be sampling from that distribution correctly yet.  To sample the gym variable correctly, you'd need to add an extra line in the `for` loop which generates a random integer on the interval `np.arange(len(gym))`.  Then use that number as a random index into the `gym` list in order to sample from the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, I recommend looking in to [Halton sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence) and similar quasi-random low-discrepancy sequences. The [ghalton](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghalton) package makes it easy to generate a deterministic but low-discrepancy sequence:

```
import ghalton as gh
sequence = gh.Halton(n)  # n is the number of dimensions you want
```

Then building on some of the other answers, you could do something like:

```
values = sequence.get(10000)  # generate a bunch of draws of
for vals in values:
    # vals will have a single sample of n quasi-random numbers
    variables = # add whatever other stuff you need to your quasi-random values
    results_dist.append(total_time(variables))
```

If you look at some of the research papers on quasi-random sequences, they have been shown to do a better job of converging for applications like Monte Carlo integration and sampling. Basically you more uniformly cover the search space while maintaining random-like properties in your samples, which leads to faster convergence in most cases.

This basically gets you a uniform distribution over `n` dimensions. If you want to have non-uniform distributions in some dimensions, you can transform your uniform distributions accordingly. I am not sure what effect this would have on the low-discrepancy property of the Halton sequence, but it might be worth investigating.